# How can I avoid image flickering with Glide

Tags: android, caching, android-glide

I'm making a preview like youtube/netflix on my application.

To do so I've got [sprite of thumbnail](https://bitdash-a.akamaihd.net/content/MI201109210084_1/thumbnails/f08e80da-bf1d-4e3d-8899-f0f6155f6efa.jpg) (a large image composed of many small one which correspond to a timeframe). Using `Glide` and `Custom Transformation` I've managed to isolate those timeframe and display them in the frame above my `progressbar`.

Even though I've loaded and created the thumbs before-hand when they are being displayed for the first time the transition between image make them flicker.

I've created an imgur to show you the behaviour : [Example in video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7r7Xs.jpg)

I've been looking on stackoverflow and found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48996119/glide-4-6-1-image-flicker-on-custom-transformation) and  [`Glide issues`](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/755#issuecomment-157995958) and found that it is due to:

> The flickering is caused by you loading images into the same view in quick succession.

I don't see how I can improve the current behaviour, all the thumbs are created before the `exoplayer` start playing and Glide only needs to display them.

here is my code:

**Custom Transformation**:

```kotlin
private const val MAX_LINES = 7
private const val MAX_COLUMNS = 7
private const val THUMBNAILS_EACH = 5000 // milliseconds

class GlideThumbnailTransformationFull(position: Long) : BitmapTransformation() {

    private val x: Int
    private val y: Int

    init {
        val square = position.toInt() / THUMBNAILS_EACH
        y = square / MAX_COLUMNS
        x = square % MAX_COLUMNS
    }

    override fun transform(pool: BitmapPool, toTransform: Bitmap, outWidth: Int, outHeight: Int): Bitmap {
        val width = toTransform.width / MAX_COLUMNS
        val height = toTransform.height / MAX_LINES

        return Bitmap.createBitmap(toTransform, x * width, y * height, width, height)
    }

    override fun updateDiskCacheKey(messageDigest: MessageDigest) {
        val data: ByteArray = ByteBuffer.allocate(8).putInt(x).putInt(y).array()
        messageDigest.update(data)
    }

    override fun hashCode(): Int {
        return (x.toString() + y.toString()).hashCode()
    }

    override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
        if (other !is GlideThumbnailTransformationFull) {
            return false
        }
        return other.x == x && other.y == y
    }
}
```

**to load the image I use**

```kotlin
GlideApp.with(imageView)
            .load(thumbnailsUrl)
            .dontAnimate()
            .skipMemoryCache(false)
            .override(Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL, Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL)
            .transform(GlideThumbnailTransformationFull(currentPosition))
            .into(imageView)
```

Answer (score 1):

https://futurestud.io/tutorials/glide-caching-basics
Have a look at this.This gives a deatiled idea of caching and other things in glide

```
Glide.with(imageView)
    .load(url)
    .transition(withCrossFade(factory))
    .apply(RequestOptions().placeholder(placeholder))
    .apply(RequestOptions.diskCacheStrategyOf(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL))
    .into(imageView)
```

Comment: I've already read this article and [this one](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/glide-how-to-choose-the-best-caching-preference) along with the [glide documentation](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/caching.html), I don't see anywhere how you can force an image to be in memory cache

Comment: This answer works for me!
I used local resource image